# Render transparent texture

Tags: rendering, texturing, transparency

I have the following problem: I have a transparent texture with a lettering. I gave the font a new look in orange. I would like to have the lettering output as a PNG file. I made the background transparent in the render settings. This is also displayed correctly in the viewport (as you can see in the picture). When I render the picture, however, everything is completely transparent and the lettering cannot be seen. Did I miss a setting? does anyone know the problem?

I look forward to an early reply.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry I might be a bit lamebrained today... you have an image with a transparent lettering and you want to save it as an image with transparent lettering in orange? Aren't there easier ways than doing it in Blender? Maybe opening it in Gimp or Photoshop, make it orange and save it?

Comment: That's fine,I understand the bloom effect of blender is pretty great. Is there any compositing you are using??

Comment: Also,try sending the blend file or at least screen shot of output settings